# Spiral of non-overlapping circles

Tags: matlab, plot, spiral

I want to create a spiral of circle markers which never overlap with each other. This is what I got so far, but it overlaps the first markers, and the last ones are too far apart from each other.

```
t = pi : pi/20 : 20*pi;
t = asind(1./t);
r = t;
x = r .* cos(t);
y = r .* sin(t);
plot(x,y,'o-');
axis equal; hold on
```

Plotting without redefining t as asinf(1/t) as follows, is shown in the second plot.

```
t = pi : pi/20 : 20*pi;
r = t;
x = r .* cos(t);
y = r .* sin(t);
plot(x,y,'o-');
```

Any ideas on how does the spacing of the angles t must be to accomplish that the markers don't overlap?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'll go ahead and state the obvious saying that the spacing should not be constant. But you'll need someone better at math than me to get the right form of the spacing.

Comment: Agreed. It's precisely the spacing what I'm trying to find. thanks!

Comment: The second formula you provided for the spacing is exactly the same as the first. Is it a mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
syms s;
scale = 10;
l = scale/2 : scale/2 : 40*scale;
t = double(arrayfun(@(y) vpasolve((0.5*(s*sqrt(1+s^2)+asinh(s)))==y,s), l));
x = t .* cos(t);
y = t .* sin(t);
plot(x,y,'o-');
pbaspect([1 1 1]);
axis(scale*[-5 5 -5 5])
```

The idea is to parameterize using the arclength of the curve. The arclength of this spiral is `l=1/2*(t*sqrt(1+t*t)+asinh(t))` (can be found using Matlab symbolic integration). To place points uniformly, we do a uniform sampling of the arclength, and find the corresponding `t` by solving the equation. Since it cannot be solved easily symbolically, we use a numerical solver.

Note that the scale and the aspect ratio of the plot is really important for it to look uniform and non-overlapping. This is why I added axis/ratio definition. Since each point is solved numerically, it can take quite some time to evaluate. There may be a faster way to do it, but at least you have a result.

I obtain the following result:

[image: Uniform Sampling Spiral]

Comment: I used Octave Online to do it since I do not have Matlab on my computer. The syntax and the behavior should be the same. Tell me if it works and if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 4):

You can approximate the arc length, greatly simplifying [Gilles-Phillipe's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55560784/7328782). This is a simplification, which means that the distance between the markers is not identical everywhere. However the distances are fairly consistent, especially further out.

The approximation here is to assume that the spiral is, locally, a circle. The arc length then is `r*dt` at a position in the spiral a distance `r` from the origin, for a change in angle of `dt` radian.

We now no longer need to solve symbolic equations. I wrote the code in a loop. I'm sure it's possible to vectorize it, making the whole thing two lines of code, but I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader.

This is the code:

```matlab
d = 1; % step size
q = 1/(2*pi); % spiral constant -- radius grows by q every 1 radian turn
N = 300; % number of points

t = 0; % initial angle
r = d; % initial radius
p = zeros(100,2);
p(1,:) = [r*cos(t),r*sin(t)]; % first point
for ii=2:N
   dt = d/r;
   t = t+dt;
   r = r+dt*q;
   p(ii,:) = [r*cos(t),r*sin(t)];
end

clf
plot(p(:,1),p(:,2),'o-') 
axis equal
```

[image: spiral with almost-equidistant markers]